# how to set strong firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Recently I got a mail from firebase in which they told me that all requests from clients are declined after 4 days and to update my security rule.

In my app, there is no need for logging, anyone can download and play quizzes but I did not allow anyone to write to the database. I manually update the database.

So please suggest to me what rule am I use to avoid that request decline problem.

My realtime database rules are-

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
```

and storage rules are-

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is way too broad for a question on Stack Overflow. I recommend you check out the documentation on writing rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: I always check the documentation first, but as the mail telling me to decline all request And I don't want my application to stop working so I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can try if

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what about the realtime database? are they perfect?